# Flash - current time plus 30 minutes

Tags: flash, time, timer

im really new to flash, how do i go about creating a variable which will get the current date and time and add 30 minutes to it ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var min:Number = 30;
var mSecs:Number = min * 60 * 1000;
var sum:Number = mSecs + date.getTime();

var newTime:Date = new Date(sum);
```

You can see some examples of turning this into functions you can reuse as well on [Adobe's livedocs website](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html).

Answer (score 1):

This gets today's date and adds 30 minutes to it.

```
var mydate:Date = new Date();
mydate.setMinutes(mydate.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Comment: according to the flash docs, setMinutes() can't accept anything larger than 59, so it's likely you'll have an error if you pass an hour mark.